# Error al leer Imagen de una BD en JAVA

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos, blob, imageicon

Buen día gente. Tengo una BD la cual tiene un campo tipo BLOB en el cual guardo Imágenes, desde JAVA puedo guardar las imágenes, el problema esta cuando intento leerlas desde JAVA para mostrarla en un jLabel.
No se a que se deba dejo parte del código a ver si me pueden ayudar.

En esta parte obtengo los datos de la BD.

```
    try {

        pst = consulta.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

        if (rs.next()) {

            Aux_count = 1;
            
            System.out.println("Foto : " + rs.getString("Foto"));
                            
            blob_img = rs.getBlob("Foto");
            
            int Aux_length_blob = (int) blob_img.length();
            byte[] dataImg = blob_img.getBytes(1, Aux_length_blob);
            
            try {
                
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataImg));
            ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);
            this.icon2 = icono;
            
            } catch (IOException iOException) {
                System.out.println("error // try  IOException");
            }                
            
            System.err.println("Encontro la Foto");

        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encontro Foto");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Consultar IMG:"+e);
    }
    bd.Desconectar();
```

En esta parte es donde trato de asignar la imagen al jLabel.

```
    Aux_Variables obj = new Aux_Variables();

    obj.consultarImg("1");

    if (obj.getAux_count() == 1) {
        System.err.println("Entro condicional");

            jLabel_img.setIcon(obj.get_icon2());

            jLabel_img.setHorizontalAlignment(jLabel_img.CENTER);
            jLabel_img.setVerticalAlignment(jLabel_img.CENTER);


    } else {
        System.err.println("No Entro condicional");
    }
```

Este es el error que me sal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "java.awt.Image.getProperty(String, java.awt.image.ImageObserver)"
> because "image" is null   at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:257)     at
> Mein.Aux_Variables.consultarImg(Aux_Variables.java:70)    at
> Formatos_Informe.Orden_Fotos.(Orden_Fotos.java:35)  at
> Formatos_Informe.Busqueda_Hub_Info.jBInforme_Tipo_4ActionPerformed(Busqueda_Hub_Info.java:327)
> at
> Formatos_Informe.Busqueda_Hub_Info$5.actionPerformed(Busqueda_Hub_Info.java:112)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

"

Comment: Código como texto, por favor. Ve a [edit] y arregla la pregunta.

Comment: Listo, espero me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Hm, estás suponiendo que `ImageIO.read` retorna algo no nulo  y ya después todo puede _malir sal_. Por favor, cambia ese messageDialog con `e` y haz un `e.printStackTrace;` para ver con más detalle en qué operación tienes algo nulo :)

Comment: Lo hice y la verdad no entiendo muy bien en donde esta el error :(

Comment: Y si vas a [edit] la pregunta y añades el stacktrace **como texto**, con eso te ayudamos a mirar? :)

Comment: Espero que te refieras a eso, soy nuevo en esto...

Comment: Eso era lo que quería decir :) Gracias. En efecto, haces `obj.consultarImg("1");` y luego tu código se queja porque haces `ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(img);`. Como no sabemos qué consulta ejecutas, sobre qué tabla con qué datos y qué sale en el `rs`, no podemos decirte más. Lo que sí es claro es que ese `rs` no trae lo que supones (aunque no viene nulo, por eso hace bien el `rs.next()`); hazle debug

Comment: El error estaba en como guardaba la Imagen en la BD, un error tonto vamos jeje, Gracias me hiciste caer encueta en donde estaba el error.

Comment: Súper! Pon la solución como respuesta, así otros sabrán qué revisar si les pasa lo mismo. Cómo debe estar la imagen guardada? Cómo la tenías? Ponlo como respuesta, te votarán positivo y la puedes marcar como aceptada después de unas horas

Comment: Listo, gracias por los consejos :)

Answer (score 1):

Bueno ya pude resolver mi problema y fue básicamente que estaba guardando los datos en la columna "Foto" de la BD de forma incorrecta.

Así es como tenia el método que me guarda la Imagen en la BD, en el método pido el "cdOT" que es el identificador único de la tabla en la BD y la ruta del archivo a guardar para así formar el `FileInputStream`, mi error esta en que mando el dato como si fuera un `String` en la variable `sql`.

```
public void guardarImg(String cdOT, String cdruta) {

        Conect bd = new Conect();
        bd.bdmym();
        Connection consulta;
        consulta = bd.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement pst = null;

        FileInputStream fi = null;

        try {

            File file = new File(cdruta);
            fi = new FileInputStream(file);

            String sql = "UPDATE mymbd.producto SET Foto = " + "\"" + fi + "\"" + " WHERE OT = " + cdOT;

            pst = consulta.prepareStatement(sql);

            pst.executeUpdate(sql);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IMG Guardada");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar IMG " + e);
        }
        bd.Desconectar();
    }
```

En esta parte corrijo esto mandando el `FileInputStream` con un `setBinaryStream` el cual es recibido por un `Stored Procedure` que me hace el UPDATE en la BD. Este seria el Código corregido.

```
public void guardarImg(String cdOT, String cdruta) {

    Conect bd = new Conect();
    bd.bdmym();
    Connection consulta;
    consulta = bd.getConnection();

    FileInputStream fi = null;

    try {

        File file = new File(cdruta);
        fi = new FileInputStream(file);

        java.sql.CallableStatement Agregar_Foto = consulta.prepareCall("{call Agregar_Foto(?, ?)}");

        Agregar_Foto.setString(1, cdOT);
        Agregar_Foto.setBinaryStream(2, fi);

        Agregar_Foto.executeQuery();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "IMG Guardada");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Aux_Variables.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar IMG " + e);
    }
    bd.Desconectar();
}
```